# EJS not rendering ejs code on client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I tried rendering EJS code that I sent from `home.js` to `home.ejs` as a string but it didn't work. I'm trying this now but nothing seems to work. My code is:

**home.js**

```
var templates = {};
templates.onScroll = fs.readFileSync('views/partials/onScrollAppendPost.ejs', 'utf-8');
res.render("users/home", {templates: templates});`
```

**home.ejs**

```
 var template = new EJS({text: <%- JSON.stringify(templates.onScroll) %>}).update('#mainContainer', {postArr: postArr});
```

**Edit:**

What im trying to do is I want to detect when a user gets to the bottom of the page. With this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
//get post data and append post
}});
```

When the user gets to the bottom of the page i want to append ejs code to the page. Basically i want to communicate between ejs and js.

Comment: To be honest, I never saw a code like that, but maybe I'm just ignorant. How did you learn it? Can you provide some tutorial or example that use a similar code?

Comment: these templates need to compile on the server itself, Browser can not compile ejs files AFAIK. you need to use templating engine

Comment: [Check this](https://coligo.io/templating-node-and-express-apps-with-ejs/)

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'it didn't work'? Are you trying to run templates on both the server and the client? It should be possible, though a bit odd. The syntax for using EJS on the client is explained here http://ejs.co/ in the section 'Browser support'.

Comment: **Edited the question** Is there any examples of browser ejs? I could not understand it from ejs.co @skirtle

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example at http://ejs.co, you first need to include a browser build of ejs in your page:

```
<script src="ejs.js"></script>
```

Then you can use EJS client-side like this:

```
var html = ejs.render('your template here', {postArr: postArr});

$('#mainContainer').html(html);
```

Here's I'm assuming `postArr` is set appropriately, possibly as the result of an AJAX request.

As you're using EJS to generate EJS it all gets a lot more difficult to understand but the relevant code in your `home.ejs` would be something like this:

```
var html = ejs.render(<%- JSON.stringify(templates.onScroll) %>, {postArr: postArr});

$('#mainContainer').html(html);
```

This assumes that the `onScroll` template doesn't `include` any other templates. You haven't specified whether `home.ejs` is being used to generate HTML or JavaScript so it's unclear precisely what other escaping considerations might apply but it's possible that won't be a problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, dealing with exams right now. This is a part of what i see on the page when i use  <%- JSON.stringify(templates.onScroll) %> `\r\n \r\n <% if(postArr[i].bestAnswer != null){ %>\r\n \r\n <% }else { %>\r\n \r\n <% } %>\r\n
\r\n <% }else if(postArr[i].rateStatus == false){ %>\r\n
\" data-status=\"downvoted\"\r\n style=\"display: flex; flex-direction: column; margin: -160px 0 0 0; position: absolute;\">\r\n \r\n
<%= postArr[i].rateCount %>

` @skirtle

Comment: I just realized it stringfies EVERYTHING after  `<%- JSON.stringify(templates.onScroll) %>` and outputs it to page :/